# how to make a memory card unreadable only for computers?

Tags: security, memory-card

I want to make my memory card unreadable for my big brother and his friend's computers. Is it possible to make my memory cards unreadable only for computers but read and writable for mobile phones or anything like that to protect from a PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows 8 pro (or 7 enterprise), you can try [Bitlocker To Go](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bitlocker-and-bitlocker-to-go.aspx).

If not, you may want to try using [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) - it isn't as straight forward, but, it will work very well.

If you want to know a more detailed guide on each let me know, but, there are many tutorials on this (and others) sites.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.I would like to know more about True crypt.Cause i use windows XP pro.Is it possible to make memory card unreadable for computers but usable for mobile phones? Please give me a way.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not - Truecrypt would need to be installed on all the machines you want to access the files from... you would then basically encrypt the entire drive. to people without Truecrypt, they would just see one huge file, but once you open it with Truecrypt, you will see all your files... Unfortunately, I do not know of a way of doing this with mobile phones.